# SQL Day of month when more than 24/28 days in a month

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a column, where users can insert the number of day for the month. Lets call the column DAY_OF_PERIOD, numbers 1-31 can be inserted there.

I wonder what should happen when number 31 is inserted for example. But the month only has 28 days. It is still required for the numbers 29, 30 and 31 to appear in the selection when the query is started on the 28th (in case it is the last day of month)

This would work when every month had the same number of days :p
DAY_OF_PERIOD=dayofmonth(sysdate)

Does anybody have an elegant solution for this?

Best regards
A

EDIT:
Added more info

the user first inserts the frequency flag: daily, weekly, monthly. And then based on the first flag the day_of_period option means different things. 1-7 (weekly) or 1-31 (monthly). And also some other information for scheduling. And based on that information the table is looped, for example, every hour. So when the user enters a 31 in there (with a monthly flag), i have to include it in the query once every month and on the 31st day.

Comment: It's usually best to store dates (and/or times) using the datetime types available in your database, rather than storing component parts separately. I'm not sure what you mean by "29, 30 and 31 to appear in the selection", but that sounds like it might be something better addressed through a reporting side rather than data that ought to be stored.

Comment: How is the column *used*? It's very hard to suggest a solution when we don't know the problem.

Comment: Well the user first inserts the frequency flag: daily, weekly, monthly. And then based on the first flag the day_of_period option means different things. 1-7 (weekly) or 1-31 (monthly).
And also some other information for scheduling. And based on that information the table is looped, for example, every hour. So when the user enters a 31 in there (with a monthly flag), i have to include it in the query once every month and on the 31st day.

Answer (score 1):

use a datepicker to insert dates.

[Link to Javascript datepicker which can be used in asp and html](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11941/JavaScript-DatePicker)

u could also use a JQuery DatePicker. Pass the date headache to the date components.that is always the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the month/year for which the users are entering the day period you can use the `lastday()` function to determine if it's valid.

```
SELECT day(last_day('2013-01-20')
```

Would return 31.

```
SELECT day(last_day('2013-02-20')
```

Would return 28.

You can use the above in your insert of data validation section to confirm the input before committing.